# Returning Local Variable Pointers - C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write a function in C to `return` the reverse of the a string that is passed into to the function.

Once the string is passed in I declare a local `char []` to fill with the reverse of the string.

However, when I compile the program I receive a warning stating `warning: function returns address of local variable      return test;`

Am I allowed to return local variable pointers from functions in C?

```
char *reverseString(char *str)
{
    int i, j;
    char test[strlen(str)];

    if(str == 0)
        return;

    for(i = 0, j = strlen(str); i < strlen(str), j >= 0; i++, j--)
        str[j] = test[i];

    return test;
}
```

Comment: No, it will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Don't use `strlen()` that way.

Comment: You want to allocate enough memory for `strlen(str) + 1` characters to properly account for the terminating `\0` character.

Comment: Out of curiosity, any chance you can just reverse the string in-place? it is trivial and puts the onus on the *caller* to make a copy if they want to retain the original.

Comment: I want to store a reversed copy of the string AND the original copy so that I can compare them both, and check to see if they're a palindrome.

Comment: Local variables are allocated/stored on the stack, and cease to exist as soon as the function returns. So the array `test` cannot be returned from the function.  The key is that `test` is not a pointer, it is an array.

Comment: I realize its unrelated to your original question, but you don't need to make a copy to check for a palindrome. [Example](http://pastebin.com/EdkbU60h). Don't do more work than you need to.

Comment: "Am I allowed to ...?" Well, yes. That's why it generates a warning and still compiles instead of aborting with an error. However, it is almost always a very bad idea - I'm not sure I can even imagine any possible "valid" use cases for returning a pointer to a variable that ceases to exist upon execution of the return statement... But, despite being a bad idea and invoking undefined behavior, it is still allowed...

Comment: Also, seeing your comment about your actual algorithm - you can check a string for being a palindrome without reversing it. The algorithm is identical to the reverse-in-place algorithm, except it compares pairs of characters instead of swapping them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need more space for a string, `strlen()` gives you the number of characters, but c strings use an extra character to mark the end of the string, the `'\0'` ascii `nul` character, so `1 + strlen(otherString)` is always required to copy a string.
2. You check `str` for `NULL` after dereferencing it. That doesn't make sense, fist check for `NULL` and then call `strlen()`.
3. Using `strlen()` that way is not a good idea, because in c the string length is not stored anywhere, calling `strlen()` computes the string basically this way

   ```
   size_t strlen(const char *string)
   {
       size_t count = 0;
       while (*string++ != '\0')
           count++;
       return count;
   }
   ```

   there you can see how important the terminating `'\0'` is, and why you should not call `strlen()` in a loop for a string whose length doesn't change.
4. If you return the address of a local variable, it will not work as you expect, because it wil be deallocated when the function returns, so you need to use dynamic allocation, for that there exists `malloc()` which makes it easy to do, so in your case it would be something like this

   ```
   char *reverseString(char *str)
   {
       size_t index;
       char  *test;
       size_t length;

       if (str == NULL)
           return NULL;

       length = strlen(str);
       test   = malloc(1 + length);
       if (test == NULL)
           return NULL;
       /* perform string reversal */
       for (index = 0 ; index < length ; index++)
           test[index] = str[length - index - 1];
       /* add the `nul` terminator */
       test[length] = '\0';
       /* return the newly allocated and initialized data */
       return test;
   }
   ```

Comment: Why is `length` typeof `size_`t but `i` typeof `int`? POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK :D

Comment: @d3l good observation, it was from the OP's code.